# Closed-form for $\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}} \exp\left(-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, closed-form

Let $a > 0$. Is there a closed-form for
$$
  \int_0^\infty \frac{a}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}} e^{-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}} dx \ ?
$$
I have searched a lot on this website and the literature, but the closest results I could find are the following integrals:
\begin{align*}
  &\int_0^\infty \left(x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) e^{-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}(1+4a) e^{-2a}, \\
  &\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{x}\left(x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right) e^{-x^2-\frac{a^2}{x^2}} dx = 2 a^2 \,\mathrm{K}_1(2a),
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{K}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

The motivation is to calculate the level crossing rate of the product of two [Rayleigh fading models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_fading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing a simplification of the integral, and then using the help of WolframAlpha, I could find a closed form which looks similar to the ones you mentioned on the question.

\begin{align*}
I(a) = & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{a}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2}}e^{-(x^2+\frac{a^2}{x^2})} dx \\
= & a\sqrt{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}e^{-a(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})} dx \quad (\text{use} \; x \mapsto \sqrt{a}x) \\
= & a\sqrt{a}\left( \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}e^{-a(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})} dx + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}e^{-a(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})} dx \right) \\
&\text{for the first integral use} \; x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} \\
= & 2a\sqrt{a}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}e^{-a(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})} dx \\
& \text{use} \; x^2 = t^2+\sqrt{t^2-1} \; \text{or} \; t = \frac12\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) \\
& = \sqrt{2a^3} \int_1^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{t}{t^2-1}}e^{-2at} dt \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} a^2 \mathrm{K}_{-\frac34}(a) \mathrm{K}_{-\frac14}(a)
\end{align*}

The last step, i.e., solving $\int_1^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{t}{t^2-1}}e^{-2at} dt$ is done by WolframAlpha. I have not solved it yet.

However, using the fact that $\; \mathrm{K}_{\alpha}(z) = \mathrm{K}_{-\alpha}(z)$ and  $$\mathrm{K}_\alpha(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 z}} e^{-z}\left(1+\frac{4 \alpha^2-1}{8 z}+\frac{\left(4 \alpha^2-1\right)\left(4 \alpha^2-9\right)}{2 !(8 z)^2}+\frac{\left(4 \alpha^2-1\right)\left(4 \alpha^2-9\right)\left(4 \alpha^2-25\right)}{3 !(8 z)^3}+\cdots\right) \quad \text { for }|\arg z|<\frac{3 \pi}{2}$$

We get that $$I(a) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} ae^{-2a} \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{16a}} - \frac{{15}}{{512a^2 }} +  \cdots } \right)$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much @SandipanSamanta, that is in fact a closed-form for the integral. Note that, as you have mentioned $\mathrm{K}_{\alpha}(z) = \mathrm{K}_{-\alpha}(z)$, so you could write the final expression simply as $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} a^2 \mathrm{K}_{\frac34}(a) \mathrm{K}_{\frac14}(a)$.

Comment: However, the series expansion is not correct. The third term is $\frac{{15}}{{512a^2 }}$ as shown in @Gary's answer.

Comment: Welcome @P.S.Dester. As I have not yet able to prove that the last integral is equal to the result at the end, I would like to know the proof, if you or somebody else get it. And maybe I've done some mistake in calculation for the asymptotic series, sorry for that.

Comment: I'm also curious for a proof of the identity. I have made a specific question to address that in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759546

Comment: @SandipanSamanta The coefficient of $a^{-2}$ is incorrect. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Expand+Exp%5B2a%5D*%282%2FPi%29*a*BesselK%5B1%2F4%2Ca%5D*BesselK%5B3%2F4%2Ca%5D+at+a%3DInfinity).

Answer (score 5):

This answer gives only an asymptotics for large $a$. Denote your integral by $I(a)$. Performing the change of variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x = \sqrt {a{\rm e}^t }$ and using the evenness of the resulting integrand yields
$$\tag{1}
I(a) = \sqrt 2 a^{3/2} {\rm e}^{ - 2a} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sqrt {\cosh t} \exp ( - 2a(\cosh t - 1))}  {\rm d}t.
$$
Performing the change of variables from $t$ to $s$ via $t = \cosh ^{ - 1} (1 + s)
$ then gives
$$
I(a) = a^{3/2} {\rm e}^{ - 2a} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\sqrt {\frac{{2(1 + s)}}{{s(2 + s)}}} {\rm e}^{ - 2as}} {\rm d}s.
$$
Since
$$
\sqrt {\frac{{2(1 + s)}}{{s(2 + s)}}}  =  s^{ - 1/2}  + \frac{1}{{4 }}s^{1/2}  - \frac{5}{{32 }}s^{3/2}  +  \ldots 
$$
as $s\to 0^+$, [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) gives the asymptotic expansion
$$
I(a) \sim \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}} a{\rm e}^{ - 2a} \!\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{16a}} - \frac{{15}}{{512a^2 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $a\to+\infty$.

**Addendum.** By [$(10.39.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.39.E2) and [$(10.32.17)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E17), $(1)$ becomes
$$
I(a) = 2\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }} a^2 \int_0^{ + \infty } {K_{1/2} (2a\cosh t)\cosh t\,{\rm d}t}  = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }} a^2 K_{3/4} (a)K_{1/4} (a)
$$
for $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$. For [$(10.32.17)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E17), see page $440$ of G. N. Watson's book *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, that is a clever approach to the problem (+1). I did not know Watson's lemma. Do you know if obtaining an asymptotic expansion for $a\to 0^+$ is possible?