# Proving that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2at}}{\sqrt{{t-\frac{1}{t}}}} dt = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}\,\mathrm{K}_{\frac34}(a) \,\mathrm{K}_{\frac14}(a)$

Tags: improper-integrals, closed-form

As the title says, I'm interested in the proof that
$$
  \int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2at}}{\sqrt{{t-\frac{1}{t}}}} dt = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}\,\mathrm{K}_{\frac34}(a) \,\mathrm{K}_{\frac14}(a)
$$
for $a>0$, where $\mathrm K$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

The motivation of this integral is related to solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4757792) other integral, but I suppose the above is interesting on its own.

Comment: Some people here do not like Mathematica code and deleted my answer. Simple substitution $t =e^u$  yields  a Laplace transform known to Mathematica. $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{u-2 a e^u}}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sinh (u)}} \, du$$  $$\frac{\sqrt{a} K_{-\frac{3}{4}}(a) K_{-\frac{1}{4}}(a)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\text{ if }\Re(a)>0$$

Comment: @RolandF, note that I specifically asked for a proof of the identity, that is probably why your answer was deleted. In fact, my version of Mathematica (13.3) already solves the original integral.

Comment: By the substitution you get a standard Laplace transform. Digging the literature for its origin  or trying to find the relevant residues is a full days work without much yield.  This field largely is covered by the mathematical tables literature, while Mathematica may produce a valid answer or nonsense often for complex integrals - as we have seen in mathematica.stackexchange.com this year in tons..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [$(10.32.17)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E17), [$(10.39.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.39.E2) and the change of variables $t=-1+\cosh s$, we find
\begin{align*}
K_{3/4} (a)K_{1/4} (a) & = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {K_{1/2} (2a\cosh s)\cosh s\,{\rm d}s}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{a}} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - 2a\cosh s} \sqrt {\cosh s} \,{\rm d}s} 
\\ & = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{a}} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - 2a(1 + t)} \sqrt {1 + t} \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\sqrt {t(t + 2)} }}}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{a}} \int_1^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - 2at} \sqrt t \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\sqrt {t^2  - 1} }}} \\ & = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{a}} \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 2at} }}{{\sqrt {t - \frac{1}{t}} }}{\rm d}t} 
\end{align*}
for $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$. For [$(10.32.17)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E17), see page $440$ of G. N. Watson's book *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*.